# What happens if the condition of equality at a point is supressed in the uniqueness theorem of covering space lifts?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

The following question is asked in my class:

Let $p:E\to X$ be a covering map and $f:Y\to X$ a countinuous map, where $Y$ is connected. Let $f'$ and $g'$ be two lifts of $f$.

What can we say about $f'$ and $g'$?

I know that the upper coditions added to $f'(y)=g'(y)$ for some $y \in Y$ lead to the uniqueness of the lift, but I can't lead to anything without that hypotesis.

Answer (score 1):

Then there are (in general) many distinct lifts. Take for example the covering $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. The map $p$ itself has infinitely many lifts $\tilde p_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $\tilde p_n(t) = t +n$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$.